# Reading XML file using MQ Stage in Datastage 9.1

Tags: xml, mq, datastage

I am trying to read a XML file using MQ stage in DS. 
Design - MQ -> XML Stage -> Seq File

XML File used -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<note> 
<to>Tove</to> 
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Reminder</heading> 
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
</note>
```

Process followed -

1) Loading MQ with the XML file 
2) Defined only 1 output column containing this XML from MQ stage in DS 
3) In XML Assembly, using 'String Set' option 
4) Providing the XSD file in Document Root 
5) Strict Validation option selected 
6) MApping the source to the target

But its throwing me the following error-

```
XML_1,0: 2015-12-14 09:43:40,801 Error [XML_Parser] [] Unable to parse the XML stream: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
2015-12-14 09:43:40,821 Error [XML_Parser] [] com.ibm.e2.xml.exceptions.XMLRuntimeException: CDIER0007E: An error occurred while reading input: language=XML, cause=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: The root element is required in a well-formed document., systemId=null, line number=2, column number=1, step=XML_Parser, source=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>. 
XMLRuntimeException$FactoryImpl.errorWhenReadingXML() 13 
RuntimeNodeBase.consumeEvent() 752 
RuntimeNodeBase.consumeEventWithLogging() 2318 
RuntimeNodeBase.consumeAction() 482 
RuntimeNodeBase.execute() 339 
NodeExecutor.processOneEvent() 163 
XMLReaderUtils.runExecutorStreaming() 201 
XMLInputStreamingHandler.itemEnd() 44 
AbstractTraverser.handleEventForHandler() 663 
AbstractTraverser.handleEvent() 534 
ItemTraverser.handleCurrentState() 91 
AbstractTraverser.continueTraversal() 475 
AbstractTraverser.startTraversal() 463 
ItemTraverser.itemBegin() 122 
AbstractTraverser.handleEventForHandler() 668 
AbstractTraverser.handleEvent() 534 
VectorTraverser.handleCurrentState() 133 
AbstractTraverser.continueTraversal() 475 
AbstractTraverser.startTraversal() 463 
AbstractRuntimeFrame.runTraverser() 1426 
AbstractRuntimeFrame.runTraverser() 1409 
UserRuntimeOperatorAdapter.runTraverser() 138 
AbstractRuntimeOperator.runTraverser() 199 
AbstractXMLProviderRuntime.process() 254 
UserRuntimeOperatorFrame.process() 93 
OperatorController.callOperatorProcess() 314 
OperatorController.runOperator() 264 
OperatorController.doReadyToExecute() 168 
OperatorController.runDataStateTransistion() 123 
OperatorController.runTransitions() 85 
OperatorController.runOperatorStep() 63 
OperatorTask.runFrame() 86 
OperatorTask.execute() 40 
AbstractTask.run() 27 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask() 886 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() 908 
Thread.run() 736
```

Any idea what is this and how can we resolve this?

I tried to read the same XML file using External Source Stage and the file got parsed properly and data got loaded into the Seq file. 
So, it means that the XML file is correct and it conforms with the XSD.

But its not working with the MQ.. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Is the real file like the one shown above?  (multiple lines in the file)  Because the error message reads like it does not like the CRLF (Carriage-Return Line-feed) or LF (Line-feed) that are in the file.  Try removing the CRLFs (or LFs).

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Or it could be that it wants a 'doctype' in line 2.
i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE note>
```